# Завершение работы кода после соытия

Tags: c#, события

Существует класс с событием:

```
public class Hearer
{
    private Hearer() { }

    private static Hearer instance;
    public static Hearer Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Hearer();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler RestartEvent;
    public void OnRestartEvent()
    {
        EventHandler temp = this.RestartEvent;
        if (temp != null)
            this.RestartEvent(this, null);
    }
}
```

В другом классе я вызываю это событие при определенном условии:

```
if(this.Users.Count>=2)
{                 
   Hearer.Instance.OnRestartEvent();
//Какой-то другой код выполнения
}
```

И в третьем классе подписываюсь на возникновение этого события:

```
Hearer.Instance.RestartEvent += Instance_RestartEvent;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения кода в Instance_RestartEvent, не выполнялся

```
//Какой-то другой код выполнения?
```

Очень нужна помощь! Разъясните!

Comment: Эмм, вынести за пределы условия? Если не нужно что-бы 

    //Какой-то другой код выполнения

выполнялся, зачем его там размещать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно по-всякому. Например, так:

```
public class SignallingEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Signalled { get; set; }
}

public class Listener // а не Hearer, конечно
{
    // ...

    public event EventHandler<SignallingEventArgs> RestartEvent;
    public bool CheckSignal()
    {
        var args = new SignallingEventArgs();
        EventHandler temp = this.RestartEvent; // а этот код зачем?
        if (temp != null)                      // у вас события многопоточны?
            this.RestartEvent(this, args);
        return args.Signalled;
    }
}

// ...
if (this.Users.Count >= 2)
{
    if (!Listener.Instance.CheckSignal())
    {
        //Какой-то другой код выполнения
    }
}

// ...
void Instance_RestartEvent(object sender, SignallingEventArgs args)
{
    // ...
    args.Signalled = true;
}
```